# Change default guest session launcher applications?

Tags: unity, launcher, guest-session

Is it possible to change the default applications that appear on the Launcher for guest sessions?

For example:

- Remove : Amazon webapp, Ubuntu One, System Options
- Add : Stellarium

(Ubuntu 12.04 and newer).

Thank you for your time and answers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Create the folder `/etc/guest-session/` if it doesn't exist

```
sudo mkdir /etc/guest-session/
```

Then open  file `/etc/guest-session/prefs.sh`

```
sudo nano /etc/guest-session/prefs.sh
```

and add the following content

```
FILE="$HOME/.config/autostart/configure-launcher.desktop"

cat << EOF > "$FILE"
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Configure launcher items
Type=Application
Exec=gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "['application://firefox.desktop', 'application://nautilus.desktop', 'application://stellarium.desktop']"
EOF

chown -R "$USER:$USER" "$FILE"
```

Change the `application://...` items to whatever you want to appear in the Launcher.

This creates a autostart command for the guest session that changes the launcher item.

You can get the current launcher items using

```
gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites
```