# How can I set a persistant proxy server setting for the guest account?

Tags: 12.04, proxy, guest-session

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 at work and we have a proxy server.  I would like to allow guests to use my computer on the guest account, but I cannot get the proxy settings to stay.  Is there a way to set the proxy setting automatically at log-in for the guest account?  The AskUbuntu question **[Change default guest session launcher applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348090/change-default-guest-session-launcher-applications/348107#348107)** shows how to configure the launcher icons.  Can I use this file to set a persistent proxy server setting?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you can use the same approach as in the other question, provided that you figure out what the command is. In 12.04 I think it would be `gconftool-2` rather than `gsettings`.

However, if you go to *System Settings -> Network -> Network proxy*, there is an "Apply system wide" button (at least in 13.04). Making the proxy settings system wide is possibly a simpler way to achieve what you want.

Another possibility: I wrote a [tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession) about guest session customization. The tutorial was originally published at [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1566078), and there a user added a [step-by-step guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1566078&page=3&p=11717490#post11717490) showing an alternative method to customize guest sessions.

Comment: The "Apply system-wide" does not seem to apply to browsers in other accounts; it allows manual proxies to be used through apt-get and the software center ("Apply system-wide" does not work at all with automatic proxies).

Comment: @HarlemSquirrel: Ok, it's probably the Firefox proxy settings you need to change. I edited my answer by adding a third para that may be helpful to your situation.

Comment: Gunnar, for some reason my guest account now seems to work with my system-wide proxy set in Ubuntu 12.04 so thanks for the info!